# VB.net find specific string in a text

Tags: html, string, vb.net

So I have this text:

> WHOIS Source:      RIPE NCC IP Address:        185.125.205.81 Country:
>   United Kingdom Network Name:
>   UK-HYDRACOM-20151111 Owner Name:        Hydra Communications Ltd CIDR:
>   185.125.204.0/22 From IP:           185.125.204.0 To IP:             185.125.207.255 Allocated:         Yes Contact Name:      Zare NOC Address:           C/O Blenheim, Elm House, 10 Fountain Court, BS32
>   4LA, Bristol Email:             ***@zare.com Abuse Email:       abuse@zare.com Phone:
>   +4402034751254

I want to retrieve the text "abuse@zare.com" by using code. How can I find this string. Note that the email address does not always contains the text "abuse". Also, the text is in HTML format

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: SO is not a place to post questions of the form "I want to do X, show me how".  It's for questions of the form "I want to do X, this is how I'm trying to do it, this is what happens when I try, show me how to fix it".  If you haven't tried then it's too soon to post here and if you have tried then you need to show us the attempt and explain how it doesn't meet your expectations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Regex is well suited for this kind of task:

```
Dim abuseEmail = Regex.Match(str, "(?<=Abuse Email:\s)\S+").Value
```

This regex matches all non-whitespace characters following the text `Abuse Email:`